# Why is なら used in this sentence この内容なら勉強になるね。

Tags: grammar, meaning

Why would なら be used if なら is conditional? Couldn't you just use は?

Comment: you could use は, but the nuance would be different. Why do you think a conditional is not ok in this sentence?

Answer (score 2):

Like Felipe's comment mentioned, I don't quite understand why you would think a conditional is not ok in this sentence. In fact, you can translate this sentence literally into English and it would make perfect sense.

> この内容なら勉強になるね
> If (it's) this content, (I) will study.

Although I think "I will be taught" is a better translation for 勉強になる, as it's a phrase you say when you get to learn something new.

Can you use は? Yes absolutely you can, but the meaning would change a little.

> この内容は勉強になるね
> As for this content, (I) will study.

A very subtle change in emphasis of the sentence, if you can see how the two English sentences differ, you can understand how the two Japanese sentences differ.

Comment: 勉強になる is very tricky to translate to English, but I would translate it to something like "If it's context, I will/can learn". I know there is no potential form in it, but the nuance sometimes hints at it. I do feel "learn" conveys it better though.